# How to redirect my DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, home-networking

I have domain I use at home, for argument sake lets call it `domain.com`.  I use this domain on my home network but I actually also own the domain. So when I load `www.domain.org` and one subdomain I want my DNS server to redirect this request to the actual internet and not my home domain.
I use the domain to identify the devices at home. How do I achieve this?
I am running BIND on an Ubuntu machine that acts as the gateway as well as DNS server

Comment: That sounds like a really bad idea because of all the confusion it causes you for nothing.  Your router can make sure that your local machines are accessed locally even if you use your public IP.  Maybe I misunderstand but I don't get using the same DNS name to refer to two different entities.

Comment: Now that I think about it twice it really is a bad idea I will resort to what Daniel has said to third level domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend moving your internal network to the third level (ie. `device1.lan.domain.org`) to avoid conflicts.

That being said, what you want is essentially subdomain delegation. IIRC it should be as easy as adding these entries:

```
www           IN      NS     ns1.example.com.
www           IN      NS     ns2.example.com.
```

Because this won’t work without internet access anyway, you can neglect all other best practices concerning delegation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `$INCLUDE` functionality in BIND.

All you need to do is create a file for all your internal names, e.g., `db.domain.com-internal`, with all your internal records in it (which you already have, just substitute the filename), and then create a second file, call it `db.domain.com-external`, which contains all the records from your external real domain minus the SOA and NS records.

At the bottom of the `db.domain.com-internal` file, add this line:
,

> $INCLUDE db.domain.com-external

This lets you logically separate the internal from the external using two files to distinguish them, but the `$INCLUDE` directive merges them together as one full view of your domain.  And before you ask, it doesn't matter that resolution of www.domain.com happens internally, whether by A record or CNAME record, the IP address your browser gets back still sends it out to your website on the Internet.

Reload, check for errors, and that's it.  Simple.

This works well since a proper split-DNS configuration (internal / external) exposes to the world a subset of the full record set that is visible internally.  That is, in general, for the external public view of a domain, you only expose publicly reachable names with IP addresses.